# How to share an entry to show up only to some users

Tags: channel-entries, entry, solspace-user, users

Hei everyone,

I am trying to build a small system for an architectural bureaux like this :

## The main architect posts a House Project (  # an entry ).

- he invites 1 or more people to join the "project"

When they log in into their account, they will see only the entry "asigned" to them

## Questions:

How can the architect invite people into "his project" ?

How can that people, once they log in, to see only the posts assigned to them ?

I thougght using  SOLSPACE USER module and let the architect select from his list the authors ( people ) so they can see the post they are assigned to, but it doesen't seem to work as I encounter the problem : there are more than 2 architects and they each have different people to assign to different projects, so the list of authors to select from will be the same for both of them and they well see each other's people...

Any solution for this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Solspace have a module called 'friends' that should be able to do what you are looking for:
http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/friends/

Answer (score 0):

Hah, I got bit by the users thing thinking it would do something similar.

My best guess would be to checkout devotee & look for some sort of coupon/special code generator to generate a code and use that to supply the end user with.

There's still the problem of assigning the code to the master entry. Maybe just setup a new field with an author set string they can use on 1 or many entries have the user be greeted with a modal or somesuch, user enters "password/key" if matches then show entry.

This fall's into non native territory, but u have a blank slate, rethink the process and arrive @ a repeatable process.

Comment: Hei, seems interesting, can you provide some more details ?

Comment: Nah, its more a concept then a "how to". EE means you can do the same thing many ways. The key is how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but this seems like it might do what you need... http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access